Bluetooth earbuds with kernel 6.8 not working
My Ubuntu system, 22.04 received an update in the form of a new kernel. Previously it was version 6.5, now it is:  Kernel: 6.8.0-40-generic
I noticed that my earbuds were not working. The output sound only came out of the laptop speakers. When I checked the sound settings, I selected the earbuds:

However, when I go to test the speakers...

The speakers are non-existent.
I double checked and went to the previous kernel and everything worked hunky dory.
I think there's something iffy with the kernel that has broken support for Bluetooth earbuds.
Thanks

EDIT
Thanks to the answer below, I downgraded from 6.8.0-40 to 6.8.0-39 and everything is working. So, there has been some change in 6.8.0-40 which has broken the support for Bluetooth earbuds.

may be relevant: https://devicetests.com/fixing-bluetooth-connection-issues-ubuntu

I have reset my bluetooth driver as I would need to do whenever I put my laptop to sleep. That has not worked at all. It should not need a whole load of editing config files. It should work almost straight out of the box.

I too experience BT audio issues on k6.8. My Jabra headphones should use A2DP sink by default when connected, but now HFP takes precedence. My headphones go to sleep within 15 min. of inactivity (no sound emitted), so whey they reconnect, I have to manually switch to A2DP sink, which is annoying. No issues on k6.5.

Same here, but so far my problem happens only with my JBL Charge 3. My JBL Flip 6 and JBL E65BTNC are working fine.

I too have started having issues with Bluetooth, similar to described above, on Ubuntu 24.04 after 6.8.0-40 kernel update. For now I reverted to 6.8.0-39 and that resolved the problem, so I would suggest to try and install that version or your last known working version.
This thread is so far the only report of this I could find, so I can only assume this must only happen on specific hardware - in my case it's Intel AX201:
$ sudo lsusb | grep Bluetooth
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 8087:0026 Intel Corp. AX201 Bluetooth


Thank you! Version 6.8.0-39 works, but not -40. I forgot to mention that my Bluetooth device is: Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0bda:c024 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth Radio
